# How do I insert values of different type to columns in my table?

Tags: sql, python-3.x, postgresql, csv

The question title might sound ridiculous, but I would explain what I want to do with example table below:

```
+------------+------------+----------------+----------+-------------------------+
|  recvtime  | entitytype |    attrname    | attrtype |        attrvalue        |
+------------+------------+----------------+----------+-------------------------+
| 2019-05-27 | Noise      | measurand      | Number   | 51.7                    |
| 2019-05-27 | Noise      | sonometerClass | Text     | 1                       |
| 2019-05-27 | Noise      | name           | Text     | City Centre             |
| 2019-05-27 | Noise      | longitude      | Number   | -8.65915                |
| 2019-05-27 | Noise      | latitude       | Number   | 41.1591                 |
| 2019-05-27 | Noise      | dateObserved   | DateTime | 2016-05-24T18:38:15.00Z |
+------------+------------+----------------+----------+-------------------------+
```

Now would like to insert more values to `attrname` and `attrvalue` columns ONLY, in which the values correspond to the following:

```
+----------------+-------------------------+
|    attrname    |        attrvalue        |
+----------------+-------------------------+
| measurand      | 38.7                    |
| sonometerClass | 2                       |
| name           | London Street           |
| longitude      | -8.603257               |
| latitude       | 41.183778               |
| dateObserved   | 2016-05-24T18:38:15.00Z |
+----------------+-------------------------+
```

How do I achieve this in SQL? I really don't mind keep all other columns with the values as they are(i.e. repeating their values).

**EDIT**

While I acknowledge the answer by Gordon Linoff, it wouldn't solve my problem because these values are actually read from a csv file of the form:

```
measurand,sonometerClass,name,longitude,latitude,dateObserved
38.7,2,London Street,-8.603257,41.183778,2016-05-24T18:38:15.00Z
90.4,1,Hospital de S. Joao,-8.603257,41.183778,2014-07-12T6:18:15.00Z
59.3,0,City Campus,-8.594866,41.178031,2014-08-12T16:10:10.00Z
64.5,1,ABC Beach,-8.607085,41.15001,2015-10-11T16:10:10.00Z
```

The values are not coming directly from user input, but read from the csv file whose form is as above.

**EDIT-2:**

I understand I would use postgres `copy` command, in fact I'm  using postgres `copy_from` in the python script. 
My specific problem is reading the values from the csv file  such that for each line of the `csv` file, values are inserted into `attrvalue` column with corresponding `attrname` updated, so that:

```
For line1: 38.7,2,London Street,-8.603257,41.183778,2016-05-24T18:38:15.00Z
```

I get the following correspondance(`attrname` set to like):

```
measurand = 38.7
sonometerClass = 2
name = London Street
longitude = -8.603257
latitude = 41.183778
dateObserved = 2016-05-24T18:38:15.00Z
```

Similarly,

```
For line2: 90.4,1,Hospital de S. Joao,-8.603257,41.183778,2014-07-12T6:18:15.00Z
```

I get the following:

```
measurand = 90.4
sonometerClass = 1
name = Hospital de S. Joao
longitude = -8.603257
latitude = 41.183778
dateObserved = 2014-07-12T6:18:15.00Z
```

All other columns remain as they are.

Comment: Please show the layout of the table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff table layout is the first table above, the second is just to show corresponding values to insert.

Comment: so you are looking for a solution to import a CSV file? Check out the COPY command or `\copy` in `psql`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I add detail to my question in Edit-2, you can see that I am using postgres `copy_from`

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be:

```
insert into t (recvtime, entitytype, attrname, attrtype,       attrvalue)
    values ('2019-05-27', 'Noise', 'measurand', 'number', '38.7'),
           ('2019-05-27', 'Noise', 'sonometerClass', 'text', '2'),
           ('2019-05-27', 'Noise', 'name', 'text', 'London Street'),
           ('2019-05-27', 'Noise', 'longitude', 'number', '-8.603257'),
           ('2019-05-27', 'Noise', 'latitude', 'number', '41.183778'),
           ('2019-05-27', 'Noise', 'dateobserved', 'datetime', '2016-05-24T18:38:15.00Z');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert records using columns specific query like below:
insert into table_name (attrname, attrvalue) values ("dateObserved", "2016-05-24T18:38:15.00Z");

Here, replace values with the expected what you want to insert.
Note: Make sure this query will be executed when there is no primary key on this table. If primary key exists on any column, we need to add that column also with unique value

Comment: Question edited to further explain my problem. There's NO primary key to the table.